# How to adjust my code so it is based on a variable input?

Tags: java

I am currently working on creating a random number generator for an assignment in my programming class. The requirements are as follows:

Write a well-documented (commented) program, “RanNumGen,” that takes an integer command-line argument “n” that indicates the number of random numbers to generate and uses the method “Math.random()” to print uniform random values between 1 and 100 (both inclusive), and then prints the minimum and maximum value. [MO1.1, MO1.2]

Sample runs would be as follows.

> java RanNumGen 5
> 67    24    31    11    80
> The minimum value is 11.
> The maximum value is 80.

> java RanNumGen 8
> 2    76    29    96    91    98    35    16
> The minimum value is 2.
> The maximum value is 98.

So far I am able to generate random integers with the code I've written. However it only generates 5 random numbers between 1-100 and it is not based on what I input when I attempt to run the program.
Below is the code I've written:

```
public class GenerateRandomNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //define range 
        int max = 100;
        int min = 1;
        int range = max - min + 1;
    
        //generate random numbers within 1 - 100
        for (int n = 1; n < 6 ; n++) {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
        
            //output is different everytime code is executed 
            System.out.println(rand);
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run the program I receive:

java RanNumGen 2

20
15
89
34
7

----I am getting 5 random integers instead of the 2 as requested.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Java and JavaScript are unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are ignoring the command line arguments entirely. And using a hardcoded six and one here (`6 - 1` is `5`):

```
for (int n = 1; n < 6 ; n++) {
```

Try something like

```
int count = 5;
if (args.length > 0) {
    count = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
```

To default to a `count` of `5`. And check if there are any command line arguments, if there are parse the first one and update `count`.

Answer (score 0):

The command line values are passed to the `main` method as an array of strings. As you have only one input, You can read the input value from the array with the `index=0` and parse that to Integer.